# Google Glass Tile insert Image from dataURL

Tags: python, django, google-mirror-api

I am writing my glassware application in Python using Django, and I have a dataURL that I want to insert as an image into a glass tile. I tried inserting the URL by itself as an image:

```
dataURL = canvas_file.value() //Just extracting the value of the dataURL from a Django form

tile = {
        "html": "<img src={0}>".format(dataURL),
        "speakableType":"Description.",
        "speakableText":message,
        "menuItems": [ { "action":"READ_ALOUD"}, ],
        "notification": {
        "level": "DEFAULT"
         }
        }

service.timeline().insert(body=tile).execute()
```

but the data url is REALLY long (so long that browsers refuse to navigate to it), and glass doesn't want to load the image from its source. Is there a way to encode the data url in Python so that I can insert it as a media attachment?

Comment: Can you use a url shortner like "g00.gl".replace("0", "o")?

Comment: How big is the image? If possible, you should try to resize the image to be 640 x 360 pixels which should reduce the size of the data URN.

Answer (score 0):

Data URIs are essentially base64 encoded images.

For example, in this image:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

this is the base64 data for the image:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

Once you have that, converting the base64 section of the data URI back into binary to stream up as an attachment is pretty straight forward:

```
import base64
import io

from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload

...

timeline_item = {'text': 'Hello world'}
media_body =  MediaIoBaseUpload(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==')), mimetype="image/png", resumable=True)

service.timeline().insert(body=timeline_item, media_body=media_body).execute()
```